# Validating "ipcmni_extend kernel parameter " - Requirement not matched IBM DB2

Tags: kernel

I've tried to install IBM DB2 v11.5.5 following
[this manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/t0008875.html). I've gotten to step 13 in *Procedure* section and I've got error, because I've installed v11.5.5. So I started *db2prereqcheck* program without parameters and got this error in section for v11.5.5:

> Validating "ipcmni_extend kernel parameter " ...
> WARNING : Requirement not matched.

It's only requirement not matched.

I tried to google solution but got nowhere. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is only a warning, (and so can be ignored in many cases) it straightforward to make the change.

But there can be a slight performance penalty, so only enable this parameter if `db2start` forces you, or if you have more than 128GB of RAM and you know that your Db2 instances will consume more than the available default IPC resources.

If you are using all defaults for ubuntu 20.04 then here is one way to make the change (i.e. to set the parameter) permanently:

- become root
- take a backup of the text file `/etc/default/grub`
- edit `/etc/default/grub` to alter the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to add the word `ipcmni_extend`
- save the modified file
- `update-grub`
- `shutdown -r now`
- after reboot, `cat /proc/cmdline` to verify `ipcmni_extend` is present
- `db2prereqcheck` will no longer show the warning.

Notes:

(1) If the kernel command-line parameter ipcmni_extend is not enabled or the system has less than 128 GB of RAM, this value is set to 32768 ( = left at default ).

(2) (RHEL advice) The ipcmni_extend parameter extends a number of unique System V Inter-process Communication (IPC) identifiers from the current maximum of 32 KB (15 bits) up to 16 MB (24 bits). As a result, users whose applications produce a lot of shared memory segments are able to create a stronger IPC identifier without exceeding the 32 KB limit.

(3) (RHEL advice) Note that in some cases using ipcmni_extend results in a small performance overhead and it should be used only if the applications need more than 32 KB of unique IPC identifier.

Comment: Thanks, that solved problems with errors in db2prereqcheck. I've thought that it was the problem with db2setup not working (freezes on second window)because I've read in IBM docs, as it wouldn't and still won't start installation process...

Comment: consider using https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/db2 for db2setup issues. Capture and study the trace from db2setup before asking questions, as that usually gives enough details about the issue to attempt a resolution.

Comment: I will, thanks a lot man